# Material UI Button is causing Invalid Hook Call

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm a beginner at React app, I just finished setting up the app and want to use [material UI for buttons](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/). 
Here's my code.

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className = "App">
      <header className='App-header'>
        <Button>Click here</Button>
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I run that and it gives me `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` and the error points to:

```
   4 | import App from './App';
   5 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,
```

This is my `package.json` just in case, but I don't think there's anything wrong there.

```
{
  "name": "schedule",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've spent so much time trying to fix this, please help

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: @RoboticReaper You don't have material in your dependencies. Can you make a reproducible example on codesandbox or else where?

Comment: oops i forgot something really important. Now I fixed it. I'm gonna post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced your code in this example

> https://codesandbox.io/embed/dreamy-euler-jhu8t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Need only install material ui with

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

And delete if no need

> from './reportWebVitals'

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to do `npm install @material-ui/core` in the terminal. It wasn't in the dependencies list before. Thanks to @Claire Lin.